# Discriminant analysis with few samples and lots of variables

Tags: classification

I want to find a classification method from a dataset with only 8 each of condition and control, and 149 measured variables. Is this possible and can someone please suggest a method? I've tried lda and it didn't like it, saying variables are collinear. I've also tried some decision trees. Any help or guidance much appreciated.

Comment: You have only 16 observations?

Comment: yes, it's using an expensive analysis looking for plasma biomarkers

Answer (score 0):

You could try feature selection and/or dimension reduction first. You may also want to discretize the data. I did some work on a data set with 20 observations a while ago where I used various simple Bayesian models with some success in [Designing food with Bayesian belief networks](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=2963565032006538433).